# String replace with "-"

Tags: fish

I want to replace the `-.` with `.` in a string, with fishshell:

```
$ string replace '-.' '.' -- 'abc-.dd'
string replace: Unknown option '-.'
```

But it fails and seems like it treat the `-` in `-.` as an option symbol.

What's the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You had the right idea with `--`, it's just in the wrong place. `--` indicates that everything after is an argument, not an option. So one would write:

```
string replace -- -. . abc-.dd
```

note that quoting isn't necessary here (but doesn't hurt anything either).